# Embed ruby into mdbook markdown files

Tags: templates, erb, mdbook

I want to embed ruby (at least ERB) in my markdown file in mdbook:

Something like:

```
# Hi

The sum of 2 + 2 is <%= 2+2 %>.
```

Desired result:

```
# Hi

The sum of 2 + 2 is 4.
```

Can I achieve that?